# Quick Look sometimes shows blank panel in Mavericks

Tags: macos, photos, preview, quicklook

I have OSX 10.9.2 and on some photos the Preview shows blank panel instead of the image. Sometimes it opens the image, other times it's blank (for the same image).

[image]

I can't find similar reports on the web. Also is there some alternative way to do that? To integrate some third-party app to show photos when tapping space bar.

Comment: This is a Mavericks Bug indeed, you could send a report to Apple about this issue.

Comment: OK, I used http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html to report and link this topic here.

Comment: I have this problem too. It's sporadic and usually happens when quicklooking through a number of high-res images (e.g. JPEGs several megabytes in size) sequentially. But once it occurs the same image continues to return blank quicklook previews.

Comment: I've seen that myself, even on prior versions of OS X.  If If I close the quicklook and open it up again the content magically shows.  Very strange.

Comment: Not only does this very obvious and annoying bug happen, but quicklook is decidedly slower as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection; killall Finder
```

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6018924?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 7):

It seems this fixed it for me:

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection && killall Finder
```

I turned text selection in the Quick Look Window on a long time ago. After disabling it, the bug is gone

Comment: will try that, thank you..  but I think I didn't turn this option on...

Answer (score 1):

I do not have that Bug on my MBA 10.9.2

I see you use the XEE as your default app for .jpg and others?

There might be a conflict so try disabling the XEE app.

Comment: I don't know but probably not... this is just a link to open XEE, I think it shouldn't intervene.

Comment: I said maybe :) just assign the Preview as you standard app for the .jpg and lets see.

Comment: I think this doesn't matter because I'm using space to preview, not double clicking on files... XEE cannot possibly be associated with previewing files. Am I right? :]

Answer (score 1):

> I just found an interesting workaround for comparing two images or just getting an image to show up: press alt to show image at 100% (and cmd to return image to fit in quick look frame). Even if the image has gone blank, this makes it come back for me.
>
> Also, if I'm moving between to files (up and down) and they each keep going blank, I can press alt (while in quick look), go to the next image and press alt, and now Finder lets me go between the two images fine.
>
> It's not a great fix since it's very temporary, but when all you want to do is see the darn picture, this really helps.

[source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25645519#25645519)

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY!  Woohoo! This fixed it!

defaults delete com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection; killall Finder

If I had a list of photographs, all with different sizes, going back one image would show the white screen, if i went back a couple more, the images would show up. Going fwd one image would do the same thing. Very consistant, I've tried many fixes.

The fix above is the only thing that's worked. Yeah, finally!

Comment: Yes, that's great! Also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually guilty here because it was me who discovered the "default write" command a few years ago that activated the hidden text selection feature. It was in my book Mac Kung Fu.

In addition to the above solution, I'd add that the following might be needed, depending on how you implemented text selection in Quick Look:

```
defaults delete -g QLEnableTextSelection
```

Then log out and back in again.